# Адаптивные блоки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

[image: есть такой]

В общем нужно реализовать так, при том блоки должны быть адаптивным.
Уже часа 2 мучаюсь с наложением одного блока на другой, но что-то не получается.

```css
.pup {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="pup"> <img  src="fon.jpg" ">
<div style="display:inline-block;position:absolute;top:30px; width:300px;">
здесь будет текст</div>
<div style="left:400px;z-index:100;position:absolute;top:30px;display:inline-block; "> <img  src="forma_svyazi.png" >
 </div>
  </div>
```

Вот, что у меня получается, еще и скролл добавился:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
.form {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: -20%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="main">
  <div class="form"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="form"></div>
</div>

body {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
.form {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: -20%;
}
```